# SMO confidence measure in weka

Tags: java, weka, classification

I'm writing a classification code using the `smo` class of weka. But what i'm yet to find is a confidence measure of the classification of an instance. It always either returns 0 or 1 when `distributionForInstance` is called. I have two classes to be classified into. Any idea how i can get this measure? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I figured out how to get this in case it might help someone. Get the source code for `SMO.java` and add it to your package. Resolve imports if any. Set `m_fitLogisticModels` to `true`. Change `smo.buildClassifier(train, cl1, cl2, false, -1, -1);` to `smo.buildClassifier(train, cl1, cl2, true, -1, -1);`. And viola ! `distributionForInstance` returns confidence scores instead of a hard 0/1.