# How to get a confidence measure for a classified instance in weka?

Tags: java, machine-learning, data-mining, weka

I'm using weka in a multi-class classification task. However I would like to get a confidence measure for each class. So suppose I have three classes Y1, Y2, Y3 and a new instance to be classified, I would like to get the confidence that the instance belong to Y1 or Y2 or Y3. Is that possible in weka? if so, how?

It's also very important to me to know how such a confidence is computed.

Comment: would that help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686562/smo-confidence-measure-in-weka

Answer (score 1):

Many classifiers will not be able to give you a confidence value.

This is, for obvious reasons, very much dependant on *which* classifier you use.

1-nearest-neighbor classification just won't yield a confidence.

Comment: How to know which classifiers give confidence values? And how to know how they were calculated?

Comment: You'll have to study the classifiers, both what was published on them, and what has been implemented in Weka... Some classifiers may well have confidence values; but it's might not be implemented in Weka. You see: no software is ever complete and bug-free.