# Evaluate the class of a sample using WEKA

Tags: java, classification, weka

I have created a model in Weka using the SMO algorithm. I am trying to evaluate a test sample using the mentioned model to classify it in my two-class problem. I am a bit confused on how to evaluate the sample using Weka Smo code. I have built an empty arff file which contains only the meta-data of the file. I calculate the sample features and I add the vector in arff file. I have created the following function Evaluate in order to evaluate a sample. File template.arff is the template which contains the meta-data of a arff file  and models/smo my model.

```
 public static void Evaluate(ArrayList<Float> temp) throws Exception {

    temp.add(Float.parseFloat("1"));
    System.out.println(temp.size());
    double dt[] = new double[temp.size()];
    for (int index = 0; index < temp.size(); index++) {
        dt[index] = temp.get(index);
    }

    double data[][] = new double[1][];
    data[0] = dt;
    weka.classifiers.Classifier c = loadModel(new File("models/"), "/smo"); // loads smo model

    File tmp = new File("template.arff"); //loads data template
    Instances dataset = new weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource(tmp.getAbsolutePath()).getDataSet();
    int numInstances = data.length;

    for (int inst = 0; inst < numInstances; inst++) {
        dataset.add(new Instance(1.0, data[inst]));
    }
    dataset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes() - 1);
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(dataset);
    //returned evaluated index
    double a = eval.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(c, dataset.instance(0));
    double arr[] = c.distributionForInstance(dataset.instance(0));


    System.out.println(" Confidence Scores");
    for (int idx = 0; idx < arr.length; idx++) {
        System.out.print(arr[idx] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I am not sure if I am right here. I create the sample file. Afterwards I am loading my model. I am wandering if my code is what I need in order to evaluate the class of sample temp. If this code is ok, how can I extract the confidence score and not the binary decision about the class?  The structure of template.arff file is:

```
@relation Dataset
@attribute Attribute0 numeric
@attribute Attribute1 numeric
@attribute Attribute2 numeric
...
@ATTRIBUTE class {1, 2}

@data
```

Moreover loadModel function is the following:

```
public static SMO loadModel(File path, String name) throws Exception {

    SMO classifier;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path + name + ".model");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    classifier = (SMO) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();

    return classifier;
}
```

I found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686562/smo-confidence-measure-in-weka) which suggest to locate the SMO.java file and change the following line `smo.buildClassifier(train, cl1, cl2, true, -1, -1);` // from false to true.
However it seems when I did so, I got the same binary output.

My training function:

```
   public void weka_train(File input, String[] options) throws Exception {   

     long start = System.nanoTime();
     File tmp = new File("data.arff");
     TwitterTrendSetters obj = new TwitterTrendSetters();
     Instances data = new weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource(
            tmp.getAbsolutePath()).getDataSet();
     data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
     Classifier c = null;
     String ctype = null;
     boolean newmodel = false;

     ctype = "SMO";
     c = new SMO();

     for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(options[i]);

     }

     c.setOptions(options);
     c.buildClassifier(data);
     newmodel = true;

     if (newmodel) {
        obj.saveModel(c, ctype, new File("models"));
     }
    }
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: I am getting as an output two values  Confidence Scores: 1.0 0.0. I  think that those values correspond to classification result. However, I am not so sure about that.

Comment: Try passing different meta-data and see if values changes.

Comment: The meta-data is standard. I cannot change something there.

Comment: yeah looks good ... What's the question?

Comment: Firstly how can I get a confidence score instead of binary result? Second question was if my code is testing properly a test sample.

Answer (score 3):

I have some suggestions but I have no idea whether they will work. Let me know if this works for you.

First use SMO not just the parent object Classifier class. I created a new method loadModelSMO as an example of this.

[SMO Class](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.html)

```
public static SMO loadModelSMO(File path, String name) throws Exception {

   SMO classifier;

   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path + name + ".model");
   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

   classifier = (SMO) ois.readObject();
   ois.close();

   return classifier;
}
```

and then

```
SMO c = loadModelSMO(new File("models/"), "/smo");
...
```

I found a article that might help you out from the mailing list subject titled
[I used SMO with logistic regression but  I always get a confidence of 1.0](http://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2012-March/055130.html)

It suggest to set use the -M to fit your logistics model which can be used through the method

```
setOptions(java.lang.String[] options)
```

Also maybe you need to set your build logistics model to true
[Confidence score in SMO](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Confidence-score-in-SMO-td13123.html)

```
c.setBuildLogisticModels(true);
```

Let me know if this helped at all.

Comment: The first part of your answer is totally out of topic. For the second part, pred variable always return either 1.0 or 0.0.

Comment: How exactly is casting a classifier class to SMO totally out of topic? From my understanding of the question you want to get the bias of each binary SMO. This can be done by casting the Classifier object to an SMO object which extends Classifier. And then you can use the bias method provided by the SMO object which can be found here http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/doc/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.html#bias()

Comment: I tried to cast to SMO my classifier. It could not locate bias function at all.

Comment: weka.classifiers.SMO c = loadModel(new File("models/"), "/smo");
I got error here since it doesnt find weka.classifiers.SMO.

Comment: I made a mistake. It should be weka.classifiers.functions.SMO not weka.classifiers.SMO

Comment: Basically the only way to get it worked, was to use SMO c = loadModel(new File("models/"), "/smo");. double [][] biases = c.bias(); return 2 values. What I noticed here, for all the testing samples I got the same exactly results.

Comment: @JoseRamon Have you tried setting the c.setBuildLogisticModels(true) before getting the distribution for instance?

Comment: I add your line and now I am getting:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at .SMO.distributionForInstance(SMO.java:1419)
 at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(Evaluation.java:1439)
 at ..Evaluate(Main.java:332)
 at ..main(Main.java:533)

Comment: where should I tried to add c.setBuildLogisticModels(true) in evaluate or in train section?

Comment: I SMO.java file I found in line 397 this declaration: BinarySMO smo = new BinarySMO();

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should try to use the option "-M" for SMO to fit logistic models, in training process. Check the solution proposed [here](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/margin-from-SMO-td8497.html). It should work!